# How to export a function from a module to another in coffeesricpt?

Tags: coffeescript, amd

For code reuse purpose I want to capture some logic in a single function and have it called in other modules

Here is the function definition

```
// Module A
define (require) ->

  doSomething(a, b, c) ->
    "#{a}?#{b}&amp;#{c}"
```

And here is how the funciton `doSomething` is used

```
// Module B

define(require) ->

   a = require 'A'

...

   class Bee
     constructor: ->
       @val = a.doSomething(1, 2, 3)
```

However in the browser, I got this error message

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: doSomething is not defined
```

What is the proper way to export/import a free function in coffeescript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
define (require) ->

  doSomething(a, b, c) ->
    "#{a}?#{b}&amp;#{c}"
```

isn't a function definition. That is really this in disguise:

```
define (require) ->
  return doSomething(a, b, c)( -> "#{a}?#{b}&amp;#{c}")
```

so your module is trying to call the `doSomething` function and then call what it returns as another function which takes a third function as an argument. Then whatever `doSomething(...)(...)` returns is sent back from the module.

So when you say this:

```
a = require 'A'
```

you're getting "who knows what" in `a` and that thing doesn't have a `doSomething` property so `a.doSomething(1,2,3)` gives you a `ReferenceError`.

I think you want to wrap your function in an object in your module:

```
define (require) ->
  doSomething: (a, b, c) ->
    "#{a}?#{b}&amp;#{c}"
```

Alternatively, you could just return the function:

```
define (require) ->
  (a, b, c) ->
    "#{a}?#{b}&amp;#{c}"
```

and then use it like this:

```
doSomething = require 'A'
doSomething(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Turns out only the last style ('just return the function') works for me